# How to render different collections at the same place?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, enums

Suppose, I have a model called Animal. This model contains enum attribute **kind** with two possible states.

```
class Animal < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum kind: [ :cat, :dog ]
end
```

Then in my controller I create corresponding instance variables collections.

```
class AnimalsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @cats = Animal.cat
    @dogs = Animal.dog
  end
end
```

In my view I got two links and two collections.

```
<h1>Animals</h1>

<b><%= link_to 'List Cats' %></b>
<b><%= link_to 'List Dogs' %></b>

<%= render partial: 'animals/cat', collection: @cats, as: :cat %>
<%= render partial: 'animals/dog', collection: @dogs, as: :dog %>
```

What is the prefered  way of displaying first collection instead of second or second one instead of the first in the same place depending on clicked link? How to do that?

Comment: You can send extra param with link_to eg. link_to "List Cats", some_path(:cat => true) and then you can check this parameter on page or controller like if params[:cat] == true render(cat) elsif params[:dog] == true render(dog)..

Comment: @chaitanyasaraf It would be highly appreciated if you could provide an example in the answer,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write following code to switch between different  lists

```
<%= link_to "List Cats", animals_path(:cat => true) if params[:dog] %>
<%= link_to "List Dogs", animals_path(:dog => true) if params[:cat] %>

<div id="list">
 <% if params[:cat] == true %>
  <%= render partial: 'animals/cat', collection: @cats, as: :cat  %>
 <% elsif params[:dog] == true  %>
  <%= render partial: 'animals/dog', collection: @dogs, as: :dog  %>
 <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. And I'm curious how would I pass in parameter by default in my view? For example, what would I do in my controller If I wanted cats displayed initially?

Comment: On view just add "else" and render partial of cats, so by default it will load cats